# Getting Error while Dockerizing webspare liberty in ubuntu 14.04 image

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, websphere-liberty

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install JRE
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip 
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jre 
RUN apt-get -y install wget

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



# Install WebSphere Liberty
ENV LIBERTY_VERSION 16.0.0_04


ARG LIBERTY_URL

ARG DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS=""

RUN LIBERTY_URL=${LIBERTY_URL:-$(wget -q -O - https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/index.yml  | grep $LIBERTY_VERSION -A 6 | sed -n 's/\s*kernel:\s//p' | tr -d '\r' )}  \
        && wget $DOWNLOAD_OPTIONS $LIBERTY_URL -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O /tmp/wlp.zip \
        && unzip -q /tmp/wlp.zip -d /opt/ibm \
        && rm /tmp/wlp.zip

ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH

# Set Path Shortcuts
ENV LOG_DIR=/logs \
        WLP_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ibm/wlp/output

RUN mkdir /logs \
        && ln -s $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/defaultServer /output \
        && ln -s /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer /config

# Configure WebSphere Liberty

RUN /opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server create \
        && rm -rf $WLP_OUTPUT_DIR/.classCache /output/workarea

COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/

EXPOSE 9080 9443

CMD ["/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server", "run", "defaultServer"]
```

while I build the dockerfile getting one error as "Step 15 : COPY docker-server /opt/ibm/docker/
lstat docker-server: no such file or directory"Please let me know how to solve this issue.Docker version is 1.12.5

Comment: are you sure the folder and/or the file exists? otherwise try to ADD the file.

Comment: Any particular reasons to build your own image rather than use official one (websphere-liberty) already available and ready to run?

Comment: We need to install our own application in ubuntu 14.04  image with all dependencies including web-spare liberty.

Comment: Now getting permission error "Error response from daemon: invalid
header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting containe
r process caused \"exec: \\\"/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server\\\": permission denie
d\"\n". after creating directory.Please let me know reason for this.

Comment: What platform are you building on? Is the docker-server binary executable before you add it to the image?